# Is there a API call or javascript to get a Tizen Web App to run full screen in portrait mode on a TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have a 32" 2023 Samsung The Frame TV with the plan of making moving art that does not rely on AR or look like a screen. Framed nicely the illusion should be pretty impressive.

I made a simple web app in Tizen Studio that loops an autoplay video. It works perfectly - but ONLY in landscape.

I need to have the TV in portrait to showcase the art properly. The TV is standing in portrait mode now and fully operates in portrait mode - but my app will only display in 16:9 in the middle of the screen.

Is there a javascript or API call in Tizen Studio that will work?

[Photo showing what is happening and what should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDGCE.jpg)

Here is my current config.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/EvolmApp01" version="1.0.0" height="3840" width="2160" viewmodes="fullscreen"> <tizen:application id="p8x2vDIuIO.EvolmApp01" package="p8x2vDIuIO" required_version="2.3"/> <author href="https://evolm.com">EVOLM</author> <content src="index.html"/> <description>Live Art</description> <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/> <icon src="icon.png"/> <tizen:metadata key="http://tizen.org/metadata/app_ui_type/base_screen_resolution" value="extensive"/> <name>EvolmApp01</name> <tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/> <tizen:setting screen-orientation="portrait" context-menu="disable" background-support="enable" encryption="disable" install-location="internal-only" hwkey-event="disable"/> </widget>`

The app should display in full screen in portrait mode. I've tried everything I can think of in HTML and CSS to make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This API](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/sero-guide.html) probably can be useful to your case.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! That didn't directly work on my TV but you gave me enough clues that I was able to use the same key name and values and got it working. SOLVED!